# ESP8266: Mismatch between generated example binaries using gen_appbin.py utility

Tags: sdk, esp8266

I use the official ESP8266 SDK v3.0.0: https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_NONOS_SDK/releases/tag/v3.0.3 and, seems I found some inconsistency in a RAW content of generated binaries.

As I understand the SDK generates the ready FW .bin file from the *.elf file using the 'gen_appbin.py'  script (delivered with SDK): https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_NONOS_SDK/blob/release/v3.0.0/tools/gen_appbin.py#L224

This script contains the following code:

```
if boot_mode == '2':
    // write irom bin head
    data_bin = struct.pack('<BBBBI',BIN_MAGIC_IROM,4,0,app,long(entry_addr,16))
    sum_size = len(data_bin)
    write_file(flash_bin_name,data_bin) // <<< **HERE IN FIRST TIME** 

    //irom0.text.bin
    combine_bin(irom0text_bin_name,flash_bin_name,0x0,0)
if boot_mode == '1':
     data_bin = struct.pack('<BBBBI',BIN_MAGIC_FLASH,3,0,app,long(entry_addr,16))
else:
     data_bin = struct.pack('<BBBBI',BIN_MAGIC_FLASH,3,byte2,byte3,long(entry_addr,16))
sum_size = len(data_bin)
write_file(flash_bin_name,data_bin) // <<< **HERE IN SECOND TIME**
```

As you can see, this code writes the 'data_bin' pattern (aka "EA 04 00 01 ...") to the resulting FW binary twice.

So, when I compile any example (e.g. AT example), then I see in a generated FW two this patterns.

BUT, a problem is that the provided AT example binaries (in SDK): https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_NONOS_SDK/tree/release/v3.0.0/bin/at/1024%2B1024

contains only one this "EA 04 00 01 ..." patern.

So, my question is: What happens? Is the 'gen_appbin.py' utility has a bugs?

PS: I have creates an issue here: https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_NONOS_SDK/issues/313

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault. All there are fine. Just somehow my output binary had duplicates of own content.